# Java post-mortem debugging?

Tags: java, debugging, exception

Is it possible to have a post-mortem ( or post-exception ) debugging session in Java ? What would the workarounds be ( if there isn't a solution for this already ) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach the debugger to a java process and set a breakpoint when a specific 
exception is received.  Is this what you need?

From
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jdb.html

> When an exception occurs for which
>   there isn't a catch statement anywhere
>   up a Java program's stack, the Java
>   runtime normally dumps an exception
>   trace and exits. When running under
>   jdb, however, that exception is
>   treated as a non-recoverable
>   breakpoint, and jdb stops at the
>   offending instruction. If that class
>   was compiled with the -g option,
>   instance and local variables can be
>   printed to determine the cause of the
>   exception.

This type of breakpoints can be set with any IDE, such as Eclipse.  Using eclipse you can also set a breakpoint on a specific exception type, even if it is caught in the normal code.

If you have something like a multi-threaded server running, and one of the threads servicing a client throws an unhandled exception, then you would be able to check the debugger and see what happens.  I don't think this is something for production, but definitively helps when testing.

The application does not have to run from the debugger, but it can be launched with the debug options as arguments:

```
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=XXXX
```

The application runs normally, but switches into "interpreted" mode when a breakpoint is hit, at least in more modern versions of the JVM.  So the performance is not affected.

Check the section about [full-speed debugging for HotSpot VM](http://java.sun.com/products/hotspot/docs/whitepaper/Java_Hotspot_v1.4.1/Java_HSpot_WP_v1.4.1_1002_1.html)

> Full Speed Debugging
>
> The Java HotSpot VM now uses
>   full-speed debugging. In previous
>   version of the VM, when debugging was
>   enabled, the program executed using
>   only the interpreter. Now, the full
>   performance advantage of HotSpot
>   technology is available to programs,
>   even with compiled code. The improved
>   performance allows long-running
>   programs to be more easily debugged.
>   It also allows testing to proceed at
>   full speed. Once there is an
>   exception, the debugger launches with
>   full visibility to code sources.

Comment: The thing is that my application will run for an undeterminate period of time , and if it will throw an exception , I would like to debug . The thing is that if I run the application in the debugger , the performance will degrade .

Comment: I've expanded the info on full speed debugging.

Comment: Hi Mario, it seems you have experience with connecting jdb to a running process..would you be able to answer my question here ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528325/attach-jdb-on-uncaught-exception....Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you'd have to wait for Java 7 for an official API - see http://tech.puredanger.com/java7#jsr326.

In the meantime, you could substitute Exception (replace base class, inject code via instrumentation, etc) to keep your data. Please note though the ClassLoader throws and catches ClassNotFoundException regularly (each new package loaded). You'd have a lot of control that way without having to modify you base code.

Comment: While there are many words in common, JSR 326 doesn't (AFAIK) address the question that was asked.  Rather, it establishes standard formats and tools for reading artifacts produced from Java programs (heap dumps, stack traces, etc).  I don't see how that would let you actually debug post-mortem.

Comment: @alex I must have assumed that by "debugging post moretem" Charade meant going over the heap / getting an accurate stack trace instant before jvm death. You're right - it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: It probably meant just like in Python, where you can simply call [`import pdb; pdb.pm()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) after any exception. Very useful for debugging.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a Solutions Architect for Replay Solutions.  They provide a "time machine" for java applications.  You can record an application while it's running (let's say, in a QA environment), then replay the recording on your development machine.  You do not need access to the database, configurations, etc.  All you need is their ReplayDIRECTOR solution and you can debug the problem in the friendly confines of your IDE.  Problems that can be replayed range from configuration issues, database exceptions to threading problems. Take a look:

http://www.replaysolutions.com

Comment: That link takes me to a scam website.